# Omitting zeros and shortening x axis automatically in an excel graph

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set of time periods (in this case 16, but I would also need this to work for much larger ranges), which will have a set of values starting at a random period and ending at a random period. The data will either be a value or a zero, and it will not be intermittent.

So for example it could run 0,0,0,0,10,12,12,11,14,16,0,0,0,0,0,0 or 0,0,10,12,12,11,14,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0. Or any other combination, including there being a value in every period.

The data is in a table with the time period in one column and the value in the next column.

Is it possible to have excel set up to automatically plot the data in a line graph, but to not plot the zero values *and automatically shorten the x axis to fit**emphasized text*.

So in the examples above the x axis would start at the first time period with a value (10) and finish at 16.

Comment: I would use large() to pick up the values and then an if() to avoid the zeros or perhaps index() with match()... just hints - have a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a pivot chart and omitting the zeros in the chart data.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, this works perfectly - all I need to do is refresh the pivot table and the chart updates.